# @synthesize IBOutlet property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm an Objective-C newbie and I'm reading "iPhone programming" by Alasdair Allan. While reading, I found this code:

```
@interface RootController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UITableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *cities;
}
// warning: remember this tableView
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

The relative implementation starts this way:

```
@implementation RootController
@synthesize tableView;
```

Now: I learnt that @synthesize is a sort of shortcut to avoid boring getters and setters.

But I've some question:

1. in the code of the implementation tableView **is never explicitly called** but the dealloc releases it;
2. if it never gets called explicitly why the @synthesize?

Is it mandatory for IBOutlets to be synthesized?

Comment: Good question, I have been working with Objective C for just over a week now, and never thought about this, I just know it complains when I don't synthesize.

Comment: By the way, that is a reason why I just hate developing software for Apple platforms. They just do not explain their Black-Magic stuff.

Comment: @das_weezul, this nib loading mechanism is explained very clearly in the documentation. See @taskinoor's answer below and/or the Resource Programming Guide.

Comment: @Firoze I object. They do not explain that IBOutlet is being removed by the preprocessor, that IBAction is being replaced with void by the preprocessor and that those two "keywords" are just a marker for InterfaceBuilder and that they are not part of the ObjectiveC Grammar

Comment: Hey, I didn't want to create a flame...   :-(

Comment: @Lotus Sorry. That wasn't my intetion either.

Comment: No problem, I thought there were all the conditions required to start   ;-)

Comment: You can avoid synthesize completely in recent XCode compiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Memory Management of Nib Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html),

> When a nib file is loaded and outlets established, the nib-loading mechanism always uses accessor methods if they are present (on both Mac OS X and iOS). Therefore, whichever platform you develop for, you should typically declare outlets using the Objective-C declared properties feature.
>
> For iOS, you should use:
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIUserInterfaceElementClass *anOutlet;
>
> You should then either synthesize the corresponding accessor methods, or implement them according to the declaration, and (in iOS) release the corresponding variable in dealloc.

Comment: So, it is mandatory to create the property that way even if the implementation section never really uses it in a "concrete" way.

Comment: Even if you don't use it in your code, the nib loading code is using it. So you should keep it.

Comment: Is this still the case with ARC in iOS 6?

Comment: @Robert Karl, sorry. I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 3):

> in the code of the implementation tableView is never explicitly called but the dealloc releases it;

That is because when you *do* assign a value to the tableView, your controller retains it, and it will need to release it when it gets dealloc'd. Don't forget, @properties declared in an interface are publicly accessible. In your case specifically, the tableView you're declaring as IBOutlet is initialized by the view controller `loadView` method using the connections you define in Interface Builder between the File's Owner and the UITableView.

> if it never gets called explicitly why the @synthesize?

You need to provide accessors for all declared @properties. They can be @synthesized, or you could write your own.

> Is it mandatory for IBOutlets to be synthesized?

No, but it's way more convenient that way. The rule enforced by the compiler is that @properties *must* have corresponding accessors (synthesized or not) in the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For reference: From Xcode 4.4 and LLVM Compiler 4.0 on the @synthesize directive is no longer required as it will be provided by default for @properties defined in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you type

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

you tell the compiler: "Listen, there will be a getter and a setter. If appropriate, use them!" And it will use them when loading the nib.

Therefore you have to implement the getter and the setter otherwise the compiler will complain.

Comment: So how should the runtime use your getter and setter while loading the nib when you didn't declared them?

Answer (score 0):

The IBoutlet pseudo-type is just a marker so that the InterfaceBuilder "knows" that the mentioned class-file has a handle/outlet to the UITableView instance.

When compiling IBOutlet is being removed by the preprocessor (InterfaceBuilder parses (looks at) the source files). It's similar with IBAction: it is being replaced with void by the preprocessor.

That said, you *could* use the reference to said instance to do stuff programmatically (Like adding/changing values of the UITableView)

Comment: Ok, that 'could' is fundamental because a programmer coming from other languages thinks that you will use what you declare...